# JavaFX: get a running total of values from an ObservableSet of DoubleProperty

Tags: java, javafx

I have an `ObservableSet<DoubleProperty>` *itemSet* which holds the `DoubleProperty` *prop1* for any number of instances of `Item`.

I want to create another `DoubleProperty` *total* that will reflect an up to date total of all `DoubleProperty`'s in *itemSet*.

The double value of each `DoubleProperty` in the set can change independently. The *total* value would need to reflect those changes.

This is the `Item` class:

```
class Item {
    DoubleProperty prop1;
    DoubleProperty prop2;

    public Item() {
        this.prop1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
        this.prop2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(2.0);

        itemSet.add(this.prop1);
    }
}
```

This is a sort of global variable class...

```
class ItemValue {
    private ItemValue itemValue = null;

    ObservableSet<DoubleProperty> itemSet = FXCollections.observableSet();
    DoubleProperty total;

    private ItemValue() {
        this.total = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);

        // create several Item's here...

        itemSet.addListener((InvalidationListener) observable -> {
        /*
        Something which binds the total
        I figure it will need to go here so that if new items get added the total will reflect that?
        */
        });
    }

    public ItemValue get() {
        if (itemValue == null) itemValue = new ItemValue();
        return itemValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built in way to do this simply. However, there's a couple of ways you could do this. The most(?) efficient, but more complicated way would be to listen to the `ObservableSet` for additions/removals, observe any current `DoubleProperty` elements, and modify the `total` property yourself.

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;

public class SomeClass {

  private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper total = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(this, "total");
  private void setTotal(double total) { this.total.set(total); }
  public final double getTotal() { return total.get(); }
  public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalProperty() { return total.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

  private final ObservableSet<DoubleProperty> propertySet = FXCollections.observableSet();
  private final ChangeListener<Number> elementListener = this::elementValueChanged;
  private final WeakChangeListener<Number> weakElementListener =
      new WeakChangeListener<>(elementListener);

  public SomeClass() {
    propertySet.addListener(this::propertySetChanged);
  }

  private void propertySetChanged(SetChangeListener.Change<? extends DoubleProperty> change) {
    if (change.wasRemoved()) {
      change.getElementRemoved().removeListener(weakElementListener);
      setTotal(getTotal() - change.getElementRemoved().get());
    }
    if (change.wasAdded()) {
      change.getElementAdded().addListener(weakElementListener);
      setTotal(getTotal() + change.getElementAdded().get());
    }
  }

  private void elementValueChanged(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                                   Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    setTotal(getTotal() - oldValue.doubleValue() + newValue.doubleValue());
  }

}
```

Here the `SetChangeListener`, whose value is a method reference to `propertySetChanged`, watches for any changes to the `ObservableSet`. When a `DoubleProperty` is *added* it adds said property's value to the current total. When a `DoubleProperty` is *removed* it subtracts said property's value from the current total. This listener also adds or removes a `ChangeListener` to or from the `DoubleProperty` when it is added or removed from the `ObservableSet`, respectively.

The `ChangeListener`, whose value is a method reference to `elementValueChanged`, updates the `total` property when the value of any `DoubleProperty` changes. It does this by first subtracting the old value and then adding the new value to the current total. It is actually the `WeakChangeListener`, which wraps the original `ChangeListener`, that is added or removed. This helps avoid potential memory leaks. Remember to maintain a strong reference to the original `ChangeListener` when using `WeakChangeListener` otherwise the original `ChangeListener` may be garbage collected too soon.

A second option is to rebuild a binding every time the `ObservableSet` is invalidated and then bind the `total` property to said binding.

```
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleExpression;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;

public class SomeClass {

  private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper total = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(this, "total");
  private void setTotal(double total) { this.total.set(total); }
  public final double getTotal() { return total.get(); }
  public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalProperty() { return total.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

  private final ObservableSet<DoubleProperty> propertySet = FXCollections.observableSet();

  public SomeClass() {
    propertySet.addListener(this::propertySetInvalidated);
  }

  private void propertySetInvalidated(Observable observable) {
    if (propertySet.isEmpty()) {
      total.unbind();
      setTotal(0.0);
    } else if (propertySet.size() == 1) {
      total.bind(propertySet.iterator().next());
    } else {
      DoubleExpression sum = null;
      for (DoubleProperty property : propertySet) {
        sum = (sum != null) ? sum.add(property) : property;
      }
      total.bind(sum);
    }
  }

}
```

In this case we add an `InvalidationListener` to the `ObservableSet`. This listener will be invoked whenever an element(s) is added to or removed from the `ObservableSet`. When this happens 1 of 3 things will happen:

1. If the `ObservableSet` is now empty unbind the `total` property and set it to zero.

   - This is a special case to deal with no elements
2. If the `ObservableSet` now only contains a single element simply bind the `total` property to said element.

   - Another special case dealing with a single element. It stops us from creating unnecessary objects and preforming unnecessary computations that would happen if we just skipped to the third branch.
3. Otherwise create one big binding that calculates the sum and then bind `total` to that binding.

   - This branch uses `DoubleExpression.add(ObservableNumberValue)`. The resulting `DoubleBinding` from that method call will update whenever one of the two observables change. This is reduced into a single `DoubleExpression` which we then bind the `total` property to.

This second option will be less efficient because it requires iterating the entire `ObservableSet` every time. It also potentially leads to a lot of `DoubleBinding` objects being created. However, you may find it simpler to code/understand and the performance hit may not be significant enough for your application.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to keep using the `Set` but I'll give your method a go.

Comment: Also, as I look at it again: will this handle an item being added/removed form the set? Would it be better for `unbind()` to be called by the invalidation listener itself?

Comment: @IanCompetent I rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the itemSet a change listener and just recalculate the total with some method every time its called.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141262/8729420.

Comment: Hmmm...not sure that will work.

If I understand correctly, a `ChangeListener` on the set will only recognise if a `DoubleProperty` in the set is added/removed/replaced, but not if the value of that `DoubleProperty` is changed. Hence my problem: I specifically need to total the value of those `DoubleProperty`'s