# JavaFX – ObservableList and list's item change

Tags: javafx, observable

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730034/java-8-observable-list-invalidation-listener-nor-change-listener-is-called-in/26734379#26734379) provides a solution for an **observable list** that will send *"list updated"* **notifications** if properties of elements of the list **change**.

In my case, elements (a **Element class**) of such observable list are complex and I don't like to implement property for each member variable. Due to this, I added into the **Element class** a **BooleanProperty** that indicates change of the class.

---

*Element Class*

```
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;

public class Element {
    // ...
    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper changeIndicatorWrapper;

    public Element() {
        //...
        changeIndicatorWrapper = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty changeIndicatorProperty() {
        return changeIndicatorWrapper.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // Some update
        changeIndicatorWrapper.set(!changeIndicatorWrapper.get());
    }
}
```

---

*Observable List*

```
ObservableList<Element> elementsObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(
    new ArrayList<>(),
    (Element element) -> new Observable[] { element.changeIndicatorProperty() }
);

elementsObservableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Element>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends Element> c) {
        System.out.println("CHANGE");
        while(c.next()) {
            if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i)
                    System.out.println(elementsObservableList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

My question is about this approach. Repeatedly set the **changeIndicatorProperty** to true not fire the change event. So, I need to reverse **changeIndicatorProperty value** `changeIndicatorWrapper.set(!changeIndicatorWrapper.get())` each time. It is strange, isn't it?

Can I force programatically the update event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is strange, isn't it?

No this isn't surprising. For a change to be triggered a change needs to happen. If the `BooleanProperty` determines no change does happen and therefore the listeners are not notified of anything, this still satisfies the contract of `Property`.

Actually a `Property` isn't needed anyways. What is needed is a `Observable` that notifies it's observers. You could do this by using the following class and calling `invalidate`:

```
public class SimpleObservable implements Observable {

    private final List<InvalidationListener> listeners = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void invalidate() {
        for (InvalidationListener listener : listeners) {
            try {
                listener.invalidated(this);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Example:

```
public class Element {

    protected final SimpleObservable observable = new SimpleObservable();

    public Observable getObservable() {
        return observable;
    }

    public static <T extends Element> ObservableList<T> observableArrayList() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(e -> new Observable[]{e.observable});
    }

    private void update() {
        observable.invalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<Element> list = Element.observableArrayList();
        list.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Element> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("update: [" + c.getFrom() + ", " + c.getTo() + ")");
                }
            }
        });
        list.addAll(new Element(), new Element(), new Element());
        list.get(1).update();
    }

}
```